# javascript error when using google maps ASP.NET GoogleMaps User Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

When I try to run the google maps on an asp .net page I get a javascript error saying that it doesn't like the key I'm using but I have the key from google

can anyone help please?

**Edit** - this is the key that google provided:

```
ABQIAAAAcPBSoXRloZCu5tYnhpZBCBRrxSVjvAJ3kkmtcIQSxWeYirsDfxTECPvByIoh90G8hcPG55N3s_3E2g
```

Code:

```
<cg1:GMap ID="gMap1" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="350px" enableServerEvents="true"
                            Visible="False" serverEventsType="AspNetPostBack" />
```

Comment: can u provide the code! or else try with a common key that google provide

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using the [GoogleMaps control for ASP.NET](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/)

Where are you setting the key?? Onload?

Try to set it at the web.config